# Getting yesterday's date through code

Tags: android, date

I am using the following code to get today's date.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

But I also want yesteday's date in the same format.

I am using

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

but I have a feeling that this will fail once the month or year changes. How do I solve this. 
Help is very welcome.

Comment: lol why do you get this feeling ? Don't you trust the android api's ?

Comment: I am very new here. Dont know what will work and what will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont' think so .. what ever the date is, it should get it and subtract it.. and return the date of day before. That is what that function is ment to do

Comment: I checked the android developer docs and I think you are correct!

Answer (score 8):

I'd do like this:

```
Date d = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
return sdf.format(d);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about subtracting a day worth of seconds from the timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

I get a previous day of specific day by this way:

```
cal.set(year, month , day);
long lastDay = cal.getTimeInMillis() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
cal.setTimeInMillis(lastDay);
```

Hope this help!